# Creating ArrayList only when it doesnt exists

Tags: android, arrays

I use an Activity to put values in an Arraylist. 
The Activity gets started in onPostExecute by an Asynctask. 
I put some parameters in the ArrayList and finish the Activity.
Again I start the Activity to put more parameteres in it (as often as I want).
This means the ArrayList only should be created the first time the Activity is started. If the ArrayList exists (and of course has values in it) only values should be added.

I check the size of the ArrayList to know if its work, and it doesnt...

I tried it this way:

```
public List<NameValuePair> out_summary;

                if(out_summary != null)
                {
                    out_summary.add(new BasicNameValuePair(ean, betriebszahlneu));
                    int out_summary_size = out_summary.size();
                    Log.d("out_summary_size", String.valueOf(out_summary_size));
                    finish();                   
                }
                else {
                out_summary = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                out_summary.add(new BasicNameValuePair(ean, betriebszahlneu));
                int out_summary_size = out_summary.size();
                Log.d("out_summary_size", String.valueOf(out_summary_size));
                finish();
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make object of this ArrayList as **static** in global class:

```
public class GlobalClass {
    public static ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

And you can access that object in your activity like this:

```
GlobalClass.obj.add("Element");
```

Comment: Can i do it static global in my MainActivity or another Activity?

Comment: yes you can also define ArrayList as static in your MainActivity.

Comment: But its a good practice to use seperate class for defining variables which are being used all around your application.